# Why do I get a mismatched type error (expected mpsc::Receiver, found ()) when using a local Futures executor?

Tags: rust, future, channel, executor

I have the following code:

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::channel::mpsc;
use futures::executor::LocalPool;
use futures::prelude::*;

struct Ping(usize);

fn main() {
    let (last_tx, mut prev_rx) = mpsc::channel::<Ping>(1);
    let mut pool = LocalPool::new();
    let mut executor = pool.executor();
    let (tx_1, rx_1) = mpsc::channel::<Ping>(1);
    let (tx_2, rx_2) = mpsc::channel::<Ping>(1);
    executor.spawn_local(rx_1.for_each(move |Ping(size)| {
        if size == 10 {
            tx_2.close();
            println!("Done 2");
        } else {
            let tx = tx_2.clone();
            tx.send(Ping(size + 1));
        }
        Ok(())
    }));

    executor.spawn_local(rx_2.for_each(move |Ping(size)| {
        if size == 10 {
            tx_1.close();
            println!("Done 1");
        } else {
            let tx = tx_1.clone();
            tx.send(Ping(size + 1));
        }
        Ok(())
    }));
}
```

It does not compile:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<futures::stream::ForEach<futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<Ping>, std::result::Result<(), futures::Never>, [closure@src/bin/futures_ring_poc.rs:16:40: 25:6 tx_2:_]> as futures::Future>::Item == ()`
  --> src/bin/futures_ring_poc.rs:16:14
   |
16 |     executor.spawn_local(rx_1.for_each(move |Ping(size)| {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<Ping>`
              found type `()`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<futures::stream::ForEach<futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<Ping>, std::result::Result<(), futures::Never>, [closure@src/bin/futures_ring_poc.rs:27:40: 36:6 tx_1:_]> as futures::Future>::Item == ()`
  --> src/bin/futures_ring_poc.rs:27:14
   |
27 |     executor.spawn_local(rx_2.for_each(move |Ping(size)| {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected struct `futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver`, found ()
   |
   = note: expected type `futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver<Ping>`
              found type `()`
```

Why? From [the docs](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/executor/struct.LocalExecutor.html#method.spawn_local) `spawn_local` should take a `()` future, which I am passing it.

Answer (score 4):

As the error message states:

> type mismatch resolving `<ForEach<Receiver<Ping>, Result<(), futures::Never>, [closure]>` as `<futures::Future>::Item == ()`

[`spawn_local`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/executor/struct.LocalExecutor.html#method.spawn_local) requires that the future passed to it have the *associated type* `Item` be the unit type / the empty tuple / `()`. Your future is not returning that type.

> should take a `()` future, which I am passing it

I do not know why you believe that to be true. [`for_each`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/trait.StreamExt.html#method.for_each) implements `Future` by [returning the stream as the `Item`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/stream/struct.ForEach.html#impl-Future).

This can be fixed by using [`map`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.2.1/futures/trait.FutureExt.html#method.map) to discard the stream:

```
executor.spawn_local(rx_1.for_each(move |Ping(size)| {
    // ...
}).map(|_| ()));
```

This doesn't allow your code to compile, but it fixes your error.

---

Making the code work is a larger change. Here's one possibility, presented without comment as it has nothing to do with your question:

```
extern crate futures;

use futures::{
    channel::mpsc::{self, Receiver, Sender},
    executor::LocalPool,
    prelude::*,
};

struct Ping(usize);

fn pinger(
    rx: Receiver<Ping>,
    tx: Sender<Ping>,
    id: &'static str,
) -> impl Future<Item = (), Error = Never> {
    rx.map_err(Never::never_into::<Box<std::error::Error>>)
        .fold(tx, move |tx, Ping(size)| {
            println!("{}: {}", id, size);

            if size >= 10 {
                println!("{}: Done", id);
                tx.close().err_into().right_future()
            } else {
                tx.send(Ping(size + 1)).err_into().left_future()
            }
        })
        .map(|_| ())
        .map_err(move |e| panic!("Task {} failed: {}", id, e))
}

fn main() {
    let mut pool = LocalPool::new();
    let mut executor = pool.executor();

    let (tx_1, rx_1) = mpsc::channel(1);
    let (tx_2, rx_2) = mpsc::channel(1);
    let tx_ignite = tx_1.clone();

    executor.spawn_local(pinger(rx_1, tx_2, "Rx 1")).unwrap();
    executor.spawn_local(pinger(rx_2, tx_1, "Rx 2")).unwrap();

    executor
        .spawn_local({
            tx_ignite
                .send(Ping(0))
                .map(drop)
                .map_err(|e| panic!("{:?}", e))
        })
        .unwrap();

    pool.run(&mut executor);
}
```